# Installing custom kernel

Tags: dual-boot, grub2, kernel

I am new to linux. 
Using Surface Pro 3 dual booted to Ubuntu 15.10 with kernel 4.2.0
I tried to use the https://github.com/neoreeps/surface-pro-3

I followed the [easy way](https://github.com/neoreeps/surface-pro-3#the-easy-way-) and ended up with a folder called linux. It seems to look very much like the linux-headers-4.2.0-18 inside /usr/src/

I tried pasting it in there using sudo cp -avr and running sudo update-grub to hopefully get the headers working. It seems that grub does not recognize the headers. Anyways I am looking for help with this seeing as how my trackpad and camera are not working.

Comment: So you cloned the repository and ran the `./build_linux.sh clone release` command before proceeding with the `cp` command?

Comment: I did exactly that.

Comment: Why did you try to copy the files? It does not work this way

Answer (score 0):

I think you were fine doing fine until you tried to copy the files.

So one way to build and install this kernel would be as follows:

```
git clone https://github.com/neoreeps/surface-pro-3.git
./build_linux.sh clone release
cd ../build && dpkg -i linux-headers* linux-image*
sudo grub-install
```

Comment: If grub is already installed would 
sudo update-grub work? Also after the clone relese command I got a large linux folder what do I do with it?

Comment: update-grub is a program used to generate the menu.lst file used by the grub bootloader, so will only work if grub is installed but that is not the point here. Why are you so concerned with the linux folder when you have the compiled kernel packages in the `build` folder?

Comment: This is mainly because I have no idea how all this works.

Comment: So after `./build_linux.sh clone release ` all the files you need, will be in the `build` folder. So you just need to following instructions in the link https://github.com/neoreeps/surface-pro-3#install-the-kernel

Comment: The linux folder is due to the following command executed by the script:

`git clone git://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git`. Which is then patched and built. The resulting compiled kernel ends up in the `build` folder. Please comment if you have more questions.

Comment: Thanks! I will try to follow the instructions when I am home.

Comment: Please accept the answer by upvoting it, if you found it helpful